# Terminate a function whenever it is executed - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I stop a function from further execution ? Answers to my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793294/how-to-stop-a-function-during-its-execution-javascript) question didn't fulfill my need of stopping/terminating a function from further execution.

I have this kind of hierarchy  of Constructor functions :

```js
//First Constructor function
function Foo() {
  this.foo1 = async function() {
    alert("Foo 1 hs bee called");
    return true;
  }
  this.foo2 = async function() {
    alert("Foo 2 hs bee called");
    return true;
  }
}

//Second Constructor function
function Bar() {
  var f = new Foo(),
    _this = this;
  f.foo1().then(function() {
    f.foo2().then(function() {
      _this.bar1();
    })
  })
  this.bar1 = function() {
    alert("Bar 1 hs bee called");
    _this.bar2();
  }
  this.bar2 = function() {
    alert("Bar 2 hs bee called");
  }
}

exports.module = {
  Bar
}
```

I have exported the second function as a module, and used that in another file in this way :

```js
//Imported Module
const myModule = require("./algorithm"); 

//Initiating the Bar() constructor
var x = new myModule.Bar();
```

This is how it works, but to make it more clear, all the work is done by the `Bar()` constructor, which hits the `Foo()` constructor for getting the data.

I hit the `Bar()` constructor when a button is clicked, but at the same time, when all these functions starts working, I want to terminate it any time, using another button on the same page. Let's say one button will initiate the functions and the other will stop the initiated functions, and this is my problem I can't go through.

Comment: You can't really do that, JavaScript is single threaded with run-to-completion semantics. AFAIK the closest you could get to faking this would be using a flag that the long running function checks periodically during it's execution. You could also shunt the work into a web worker where you at least won't block.

Comment: In what way did the answer you link to not work? Show us that attempt as that would basically be what you would do, setup a flag that you would at some point set and each of your async methods would check throughout its execution to see if it needs to `return`. More than likely you just didn't setup the flag correctly or did not check it correctly

Comment: What are foo and bar? Should there be `alert`, or is there something else? Is this notification system or what?  Explaining your case better and providing real (yet simplified) code may help. Otherwise you will keep receiving answers that you can't make use of, because the question was asked incorrectly.

Comment: what part of that code runs at NodeJS? I'm not sure but it sounds like you are trying to stop execution code on server side that _has already been finished_

Comment: @skyboyer yes, the code is server side, but the execution isn't finished. Because its continuously scraps the site. I just got a solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution, as @Jared Smith mentioned in the comments, the only thing I have done is to add a Flag which was, `TERMINATE_FUNCTION = false`. Whenever the stop button is clicked, the `TERMINATE_FUNCTION` is set to `true` and on each functions in `Foo()`  constructor it's been checked whether the `TERMINATE_FUNCTION === true` or not, both in the beginning and return time of the functions, and there it stop the function :

The code is :

```js
//Boolean variable
TERMINATE_FUNCTION = false;

//Listen to event occured
event.on("stopScrapping", function(b) {
  TERMINATE_FUNCTION = b;
});


//First Constructor function
function Foo() {
  if (TERMINATE_FUNCTION) return;
  this.foo1 = async function() {
    alert("Foo 1 hs bee called");
    if (!TERMINATE_FUNCTION) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return "SCRAPPER_STOPPED";
    }
  }
  this.foo2 = async function() {
    if (TERMINATE_FUNCTION) return;
    alert("Foo 2 hs bee called");
    if (!TERMINATE_FUNCTION) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return "SCRAPPER_STOPPED";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So far it seems goal is to control one NodeJS-based processing(running infinite loop) from completely different process/request(initiating by clicking button in browser).

There are different ways to implement [inter-process communication](https://medium.com/@NorbertdeLangen/communicating-between-nodejs-processes-4e68be42b917)(that is how it's named). One of them is [node-ipc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc)

Completely different approach could be moving this continuous operation to some queue manager. This way you might get additional abilities like failproof execution(so you can continue process exactly from point where it broke) or transparent parallelization.