# How to stop execution of function on button click in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I have 3 files, **electron.js**, **runme.js** and **homepage.js**. When the button is clicked on **homepage.js**, `runme()` is called from **runme.js** and is executed. This is a snippet of how it runs:

**main.js**

```
...
ipcRenderer.send('startIt');
```

**electron.js**

```
ipcMain.on('startIt', function ()){
   const {runme} = require('./runme.js');
   runme();
});
```

However, when another button is clicked, I would like the execution of `runme()` to stop. How would I implement this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793294/how-to-stop-a-function-during-its-execution-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use promises and a cancelation token to cancel it. Instead of running a function, you can use a promise that wraps the function and control it by a cancelation token. Here is a link that may help you :
https://gist.github.com/danharper/ad6ca574184589dea28d